# change layouts, but not restart activity on my Android App

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, orientation, restart

I want my app to go from portrait to landscape and change from layout1 to layout2 but not restart the activity.
It goes from layout1 to layout2 nicely, but restarts the activity every time it switches from portrait to landscape and landscape to portrait and i want to just run the activity once then keep it there.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Android restarts the activity whenever orientation changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity restart on rotation Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in manifest and handle the screen contents manually by overriding `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: when i add that to the activity, my layout2(landscape) looks layout1 cuz every thing is messed up and my stuff isnt in the right positions, so i no its not changing.   and what do i put in onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: inflate new views to your parent layout in onConfigurationChanged

Comment: perhaps try using `setContentview` in **onConfigurationChanged** the same way as you do in **onCreate** method